# Semi-circular Color Wheel in R or Python

Tags: python, r, colors

I want to create a semi-circular color palette.
I only know how to make a color wheel using the following commands in R:

```
pie(rep(1,n), col=rainbow(n))
```

This one creates one full circle.

The desired output is something like this:

[image: Desired output]

The saturation changes from the inner circles to the outer circles.

Any suggestions on how I can do this in R or python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well It's quite hacky but how about something like this using R?

[image: Semi-circular color wheel], 
Get color scale

```
ramp <- colorRamp(c("blue", "white"))
blue <- rgb( ramp(seq(0, 1, length = 5)), max = 255)

ramp <- colorRamp(c("blueviolet", "white"))
blueviolet <- rgb( ramp(seq(0, 1, length = 5)), max = 255)

ramp <- colorRamp(c("violet", "white"))
violet <- rgb( ramp(seq(0, 1, length = 5)), max = 255)

ramp <- colorRamp(c("violetred", "white"))
violetred <- rgb( ramp(seq(0, 1, length = 5)), max = 255)

ramp <- colorRamp(c("red", "white"))
red <- rgb( ramp(seq(0, 1, length = 5)), max = 255)

ramp <- colorRamp(c("orangered", "white"))
orangered <- rgb( ramp(seq(0, 1, length = 5)), max = 255)
```

Function to draw pie charts of varying size

```
pie.fun <- function(rad,pos){
   pie(rep(1,12), border = "white", radius = rad, labels=NA,
     col=c(orangered[pos], red[pos], violetred[pos],violet[pos],blueviolet[pos],blue[pos],rep("#FFFFFF",6)))
par(new=T)
}
```

Draw pie charts

```
pie.fun(rad=1,pos=1)
pie.fun(rad=0.8,pos=2)
pie.fun(rad=0.6,pos=3)
pie.fun(rad=0.4,pos=4)
```

Draw final white one

```
pie(rep(1,12), border = "white", radius = 0.2, labels = NA, 
    col=c(rep("#FFFFFF",12)))
```

Add an arrow with a label

```
arrows(0.2, -0.1, 1, -0.1, xpd = TRUE, lwd=2)
text(0.6, -0.35, "Increasing \nsaturation", cex = 1.6)
```

Add some coloured labels

```
text(-1.2, 0.35, "Blue", cex = 1.6, col="blue")
text(-1.2, 0.75, "Blue Violet", cex = 1.6, col="blueviolet")
text(-0.6, 1, "Violet", cex = 1.6, col="violet")
text(0.75, 1, "Red Violet", cex = 1.6, col="violetred")
text(1, 0.75, "Red", cex = 1.6, col="red")
text(1.5, 0.2, "Red Orange", cex = 1.6, col="orangered")
```